# Is there any way to store an additional attribute in a DropDownList populated using AJAX apart from value/text?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I'm using Ajax to populate a DropDownList, when the user selects an item in this DropDownList I need to show a date in another field and this date is a field present in DropdownList entity itself, it would be perfect to add all 3 fields from that entity (value/text/date) in the DropDownList. I'm already getting them via Ajax. So, is there any way to do it? If not I think I'll try adding an additional DropDownList (hidden) or something like that, but this idea is not very nice since I would need to update that additional control on every user interaction.

**EDIT:** Adding Ajax call and DropDown related code, i'm adding 2 fields value/text, but I need a third one:

```
    function GetLote(_idProducto) {
    $("#FechaVencimiento").val('');
    var procemessage = "<option value='0'> Cargando...</option>";
    $("#ddllote").html(procemessage).show();

    var data = JSON.stringify({
        idProducto: _idProducto
    });

    return $.ajax({
        url: "/Deposito/GetLotesPorProducto",
        data: data,
        cache: false,
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'POST',
        success: function (data) {
            var markup = "<option value='0'>Seleccionar..</option>";
            for (var x = 0; x < data.length; x++) {
                markup += "<option value=" + data[x].Value + ">" + data[x].Text + "</option>";
            }
            $("#ddllote").html(markup).show();

        },
        error: function (reponse) {
            alert("error : " + reponse);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Sure, use a closure, or an object indexed by something unique to an item, or a  `data-` attribute - post the code?

Comment: I recommend using `data-` attribute or unique indexer for that. No need to use additional hidden dropdown list helper.

Comment: Thanks Tetsuya, but how would you add/use that? I'm already adding value and text on this DropDownList. Updated my post, see my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you want to pass three fields i.e. text, value and date and you are using AJAX and jquery. You can use dropdown's other properties such as for text user `Text`, for value use `Value` and for date you may use `innerText`.
So this would be something like this:

```
for (var x = 0; x < data.length; x++) {
     markup += "<option value=" + data[x].Value + ">" + data[x].Text + "</option>";
         }
    $("#ddllote").html(markup).show()

 for (var x = 0; x < data.length; x++) {
       $('#ddllote')[x].innerText=data.Date
             } //Here i have looped again to caputure the Date.
```

Now where ever you want to use Date of selected item, you can do so by using `innerText` of selected item.

```
var DateinAnotherField= $('#ddlloteoption:selected').innerText;
```